# How to make variable custom data available to custom extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Maybe google haven't learned yet or I'm just not able to construct the correct magical search text or this is just not possible to do.

Short description. I'm creating a custom extension to Code. Code will be launched by another application. This other application needs to hand over some information to Code and to the extension dependent upon where Code is launched from but I have no idea how I can accomplish this. When a command is issued from the Pallette the extension will then use this information to do specific stuff.

I've been looking into commandline arguments but I cannot find documentation or google searches that show me how an extension can access the commandline and parse the arguments.

Arguments could be customerIDs and other specific data that neither Code nor the extension can find on its own unless some kind of value is pushed from the launching application into Code...

Am I to assume that its not possible for an extension to read commandline arguments or am I just stupidly bad at VS Code bla bla google searches?

I've added an argument to launch.json "--testparameter=testvalue" and I see that code.exe is launched with this parameter but how my extension gets access to this parameter is beyond me...

Answer (score 0):

We solved this by having the other application add all the settings we need to the .code-workspace file. That data can easily be accessed by using the build in workspace configuration objects. Say the file contains a setting called 'extension.friendlyname' this is how we read it:

```
getFriendlyName(): string
{
    return this.getConfig('extension.friendlyname');
}

private getConfig(configName:string): string
{
    const configuration = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration();
    const configValue = configuration.get(configName);
    return  String(configValue);
}
```